# SDL2: could SDL_LockTexture be used in another thread?

Tags: sdl-2

I changed the teststreaming.c in SDL2 release package to try to place SDL_LockTexture action in another thread. I'd like to verify if it works or not because my code need this feature.

My changes are quit simple as below:

```
void UpdateTexture(SDL_Texture *texture, int frame)
{
    SDL_LockTexture(texture, NULL, &pixels, &pitch);
    /*hanlde the pixels*/
    SDL_UnlockTexture(texture);
}

int updateStreamFunction( void* data )
{
    int frame = 0;
    SDL_Texture *MooseTexture; 

    MooseTexture = (SDL_Texture *)data;
    while (gRunning){
        frame = (frame + 1) % MOOSEFRAMES_COUNT;
        UpdateTexture(MooseTexture, frame);
        SDL_Delay(40);
    }
    printf("quit the thread: updateStreamThread\n");
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    .....
    MooseTexture = SDL_CreateTexture(renderer, SDL_PIXELFORMAT_ARGB8888, SDL_TEXTUREACCESS_STREAMING, MOOSEPIC_W, MOOSEPIC_H);
    if (!MooseTexture) {
        SDL_LogError(SDL_LOG_CATEGORY_APPLICATION, "Couldn't set create texture: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
        quit(5);
    }

    threadID = SDL_CreateThread( updateStreamFunction, "updateStreamThread", (void*)MooseTexture );
    ....
    SDL_RenderClear(renderer);   
    SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, MooseTexture, NULL, NULL);        
    SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
}
```

However, the changes don't work for me. It displays nothing but some garbage data. but if I put the UpdateTexture() right before the SDL_RenderClear(renderer) in the same thread where the window/render/texture are created. it works fine.

So are there any limitation no manipulating the texture in the different thread from the main thread? If it is, what's the best way to meet my request(the displayed data are in the different thread)?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Just for future reference:

Take a look at the above comment from following link which stated "*These functions must be called from the main thread.*" The file last modified was 2014-12-07 at this time writing and SDL_LockTexture is inside this header.
http://www.libsdl.org/tmp/SDL/include/SDL_render.h